# rethinkdb orderby case insensitive

Tags: node.js, database, sql-order-by, rethinkdb

I want to get all data order by name in case insensitive manner. But i am getting data in this order

- lower case alphabets
- Numerics
- Upper case alphabets
  Is there any way to get data lower and upper case in same way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following table:

```
[{name: "hillary"}, {name: "Donald"}]
```

In order to `orderBy` case-insensitively by `name`, use the following:

```
table.orderBy(r.row("name").downcase())
```

Please note that as your data grows, you'd might want to create an index, for example:

```
table.indexCreate('name_case_insensitive', r.row('name').downcase())
```

and use it by:

```
table.orderBy({index: 'name_case_insensitive'})
```